# Google places autocomplete on fountain reveal modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation, google-places-api

I'm binding the autocomplete event to the element and it works like a charm if I render it on page load:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {types: ['(cities)']});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
     // my code
}
```

However, when I hide it on page load in a modal (specially using the zurb-foundation revealModal), the autocomplete event won't bind to the element.

How can I get the autocomplete event to bind, even when the input box isn't visible on page load?